# Will commercially produced soap coated in epoxy resin last?

Tags: preservation, epoxy-resin

I have started to resin-coat certain novelty soaps. I first coat in mod podge, then I give it 2 layers of epoxy glass resin. It is looking fabulous, but someone told me that soap has too much water in it to coat in resin. What will happen to it? Will it last?

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly your desired outcome is? Do you want to encase a (dry) bar of soap in a layer of epoxy resin or have I misunderstood your question? Have you already done that and the result was not as expected? Or have you done it, the result was OK and now you wonder why someone would tell you that it's impossible?

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully better reflect what you wish to know, feel free to further edit if I've misjudged the intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once epoxy resin is cured, it's extremely stable and resilient against mechanical and chemical damage. It's impossible to dissolve cured resin in water, so your soap is well protected.

Adding water to resin *before* it's cured is a problem, though, and probably the reason why the person told you it's impossible. As a rule of thumb, if you add other substances to the epoxy resin (like paint, ink or other water solutions), you cannot add more than 10% of the epoxi's volume. If you add too much other stuff, the epoxy will never cure completely and stay soft or bendable, tacky or even runny like honey forever.

Comment: Thank you! You have answered my question. The resin worked perfectly over the soaps and they look amazing. I just needed to know if this project had longevity. Your advice re adding paint makes sense and is extremely helpful for my project. I am very glad I found this forum. 

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please consider accepting it. Have a look at the [tour] to see how it's done.

Comment: @Tammy Hi, could you please post some pics to show what you were successful at making, please. I read it all, and i am interested in resin art, but could not visualize what the achievement was.